# How to edit size of an item in navigationView of the design support library?

Tags: android, android-layout

Just started to checkout navigationView of the Design Support Library .

The thing is , I'm able to change the color of icon and text of items in the drawer but not the font size or in general textAppearence

Can anyone help me out with this.

Thanks .

Comment: Do you have any code that shows what you're doing? It's really difficult to find out what might be wrong without it.

Comment: Thanks but the app:theme attribute worked like charm . Next time will think twice before posting stupid like this . Should I remove the post?

Answer (score 3):

Oops .. just figured it out . Just set the "app:theme" attribute of the NavigtionView to your style .

Like

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/shitstuff"
    app:theme="@style/ItemStyle"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/shitx"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"/>
```

And in your styles.xml add :

```
    <style name="ItemStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>
```